# get_stylesheet_directory() vs get_template_directory() for child theme

Tags: child-theme

Let's say I've the following file in my parent theme folder: `'theme-folder/inc/custom.php'`

Then I created a child theme.

How can I check if that file exists in the child theme, then fetch it, otherwise fetch it from the parent theme?

`get_template_directory()` always fetches the file from the parent theme.

While `get_stylesheet_directory()` requires the file to exists in the child theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`locate_template`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) will attempt to find the specified file in the child theme, and fall back to the parent theme if it does not exist:

```
locate_template('inc/custom.php', true);
```

Setting the second parameter to `true` causes it to require the file instead of just determining the path.

As the name suggests, `locate_template` is meant for loading template files. It has some additional overhead that you most likely don't need for loading libraries. A stripped down version would be:

```
function load_theme_file($path) {
    if ( file_exists( STYLESHEETPATH . '/' . $path )) {
        include( STYLESHEETPATH . '/' . $path );
    } else {
        require( TEMPLATEPATH . '/' . $path );
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
load_theme_file('inc/custom.php');
```

---

Edit: I just wanted to provide a quick note about potential issues with this overall approach.

Letting a child theme override files works well for templates, but for libraries there is more room for error. If a child theme needs to modify a single function, you would have to copy that entire file, overriding every function in that file in the process.

If the parent theme is updated and changes have been made to any of the functions in the overwritten file it can cause problems. You can mitigate this issue by breaking up your libraries into smaller chunks, but that can make your code base harder to maintain.

A better solution, in my opinion, is to use an object oriented approach. Allow a child theme to *extend* classes you define and then use the child theme's class. In  the implementing classes the child theme would only have to define methods it needs to overwrite. In the parent theme you could specify which methods should not be overwritten by making them `final`.

You can also mitigate the need for child themes to replace entire files by using filters and actions generously.

Comment: I think I'm going to use `load_theme_file` function. Does it have any drawbacks?

Comment: @AhmedSaad Nothing comes to mind. For what you are trying to do I can't think of a more straightforward approach.

Comment: Apparently, `include` inside this function is not the same as `include` outside it. Looks like I've to use `global` for some variables in the included file. Is it normal?

Comment: One of the things `locate_template` does is import some global variables into the current scope. I stripped that out because for libraries this isn't necessary; a function would have to import the variable regardless. If you need access to all of those variables without importing them use `locate_template`.

Comment: @AhmedSaad I added a note about potential drawbacks.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to depend on filters and actions actually. I solved my main problem by using `if ( file_exists( STYLESHEETPATH . '/' . $path ))` checker, but without `load_theme_file` function, and everything is great now.

Comment: @AhmedSaad I see the problem. When you call a function that includes a file, that included file will be in the scope of that function. If you want to include a file in the current scope, you have to call `include` directly. That's why you can't access those variables when you call `load_theme_file`.

Comment: Yes, all what I needed is if `( file_exists() )` and require/include outside a function scope, because `get_template_part()` and `locate_template()` didn't do the job. Again, thank you! Have a good day.

Answer (score 2):

[`get_template_part()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) would do that, if I understand your question.

```
get_template_part('inc/custom');
```

It is sort of built to do exactly that, if I am reading you right:

> Makes it easy for a theme to reuse sections of code and an easy way
>   for child themes to replace sections of their parent theme.

Comment: I heard that you should use `require_once` instead of `get_template_part` for including your custom php files in the theme.

Comment: Why? Where did you hear that?

Comment: @AhmedSaad very probably reason you heard that is `get_template_part` don't use `require_once`, but `require`, it means that in theory a lib may be required more than once using `get_template_part`. Note that the answer you accepted uses `include` as well (instead of `include_once` or `require_once`, that's better). Moreover, you don't need to manually throw exception using `require_once` because `require_once` will do that for you.

Comment: In this case, loading a library twice shouldn't be an issue as it is an either/or case-- either load the child file or the parent.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Here's where I read it: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/11/17/how-to-load-files-within-wordpress-themes... Start reading from 'One thing I’ve seen in some themes is the use of the...'.

Comment: "This is absolutely the wrong way to load function files. Please do not do this. That’s a template-loading function, ***which will allow child themes to overwrite the file***." -- the point being made is conditional. It is wrong because the child theme can overwrite the file. However, in your case, that is ***exactly*** what you want to happen. Doing things the way you are, with the accepted answer, is just rewriting code already in place.

Comment: I thought the point is that you should use require/include if you're going to load a file with **functions**, such as functions.php. But you may use get_template_part if you're going to load a normal template, i.e: 'get_template_part('loop'). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I just did correct you. You are doing exactly the same thing you are just writing new code to do it. If you ***don't*** want a child to overwrite the file use `include` or `require`. If you do, use `get_template_part()` or reinvent the wheel. Your choice.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I disagree with your point about reinventing the wheel. `get_template_part` does a bunch of stuff you don't need it to, then it calls `locate_template` which does a bunch of stuff you don't need it do, then it does essentially the same thing as the function I wrote. It's a small optimization and usually I wouldn't bother, but there isn't a lot of complexity here so why not?